# AWK to print min max values of unique value in column

Tags: awk, max, min

I am trying to use awk to do the following:

Input file:

```
6:28866209    NA     NA     NA     8.51368e-06   Y  
6:28856689    1   0.007828      1      1.50247e-06   X  
6:28856740    2     0.007828      1      1.50247e-06   Y   
6:28856889    3   7.51E-08      3     1.50247e-06   X
```

I want to:

- Get min and max of column 5 for each independent value in column 6
- Print the min max in the file for each column 5 at the end of the file

The file can have different N columns, but all have at least columns 1-8, which are the same in each of my files.

Output:

```
6:28866209 NA NA NA 8.51368e-06 Y 8.51368e-06 1.50247e-06 
6:28856689 1 0.007828 1 1.50247e-06 X 1.50247e-061.50247e-06 
6:28856740 2 0.007828 1 1.50247e-06 Y 8.51368e-06 1.50247e-06 
6:28856889 3 7.51E-08 3 1.50247e-06 X 1.50247e-06 1.50247e-06
```

I have attempted this using the following awk command, but I am only getting back the first value in column 6...

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";FS="\t"}{if (a[$6] == "") a[$6]=$5; if (a[$6] > $5) {a[$6]=$5}} {if (b[$6] == "") b[$6]=$5; if (b[$6] < $5) {b[$6]=$5}} END {if (i=$6) print $0,i,a[i],b[i]}' FILE
```

Comment: In the `END` part, loop through all array elements rather than just pick one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the easiest to do is using a double pass of the file :

```
awk '(NR==FNR) && !($6 in min) { min[$6] = $5; max[$6] = $5; next }
     (NR==FNR) { m=min[$6]; M=max[$6];
                 min[$6] = $5<m ? $5 : m;
                 max[$6] = $5>M ? $5 : M;
                 next; }
     {print $0,min[$6],max[$6] }' <file> <file>
```

Your original code has the following flaw. The `END` statement is only executed when the end of the file is reached. You attempt to print the full file, but you did not store any lines in the parsing.

A correction to your original idea is :

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";FS="\t"}
     {if (a[$6] == "") a[$6]=$5;
      if (a[$6] > $5) {a[$6]=$5}
     }
     {if (b[$6] == "") b[$6]=$5;
      if (b[$6] < $5) {b[$6]=$5}
     }
     { c[NR]=$0; d[NR]=$6 }
     END { for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) print c[i],a[d[i]],b[d[i]] }' FILE
```

Here, I stored the full `FILE` in array `c` which is indexed by the line-number `NR`. I also store the index `$6` in array `d`. At the end, I loop trough all lines I stored and print what is expected.

- The downside of this approach is that you have to store the full file in memory.
- The downside of my proposal, is that you have to read the full file twice from disk.

Comment: That's great. I can get your correction to my attempt to work on my file (once I adjust the `}` to `)` in `i=1;i<=NR;i++}`). Unfortunately I cannot get your own version to work. It prints the same value for min and max. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @LauraC thanks. I have updated the part of the for loop. And in my code there was a `!` missing in the first line. Both have been updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR<NR{$7=m[$6];$8=M[$6];print;next} (!M[$6])||$5>M[$6]{M[$6]=$5}(!m[$6])||$5<m[$6]{m[$6]=$5}' file file
```

with comment

```
awk '
   # optional format
   BEGIN { OFS=FS="\t"}

   # for second pass (second file read)
   FNR<NR{
      # add a column 7 and 8 with value of min and max correponsing to column 5
      $7=m[$6];$8=M[$6]
      # print it and reda next line (don't go further in script)
      print;next}

   # this point is only reach by first file read
   # if Max is unknow or value 5  bigger than max
   (!M[$6])||$5>M[$6]{
      # set new max
      M[$6]=$5}
   # do the same for min
   (!m[$6])||$5<m[$6]{m[$6]=$5}
   # read 2 times the same file (first to find min/max, second to print it)
   ' sample.txt sample.txt
```